# Author image not rendering in node twig file

Tags: theming

I have created node for a Article content type. And I am trying to extract out author information in `node--article.html.twig` file.

I am sucessfully able to fetch out Author name `{{ author_name }}`, author bio `{{ node.Owner.field_bio.value}}`.

But I am facing issue to find out author image. When I tried to print `{{ kint(author_picture) }}` it returned me null. But when I vistited link: http://drupal-site.com/user/2, I can see author image there. I am bit consfused on need help on showing author image in node.

Any help is appriciated.

Answer (score 0):

To get the image `uri` value, try the following:

```
{{ node.Owner.user_picture.0.entity.uri.value }}
```